# sshd_config how to allow one user to have full unrestricted sftp and allow ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, authentication, sftp

I changed sshd_config to jail users within specific group into their home directory. changed subsystem to sftp internal-sftp  and used forcecommand: internal-sftp

However, this prevented the admin user on ubuntu from accessing sftp at all.

How to allow user let's call him 'admin' unrestricted access and not affect ssh privilege?  admin uses key authentication.

I searched for documentation on forcecommand and subsystem but couldn't find much.

Currently I have this

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp intenal-sftp

Match Group somegroup
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Comment: What does "from accessing sftp at all" mean? What errors you get on client and on server side? What groups is `admin` in?

Comment: I wanted to try winscp but that closes window without saying anything or logging in.  on filezilla it says: "Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server".   on the server side auth.log shows that session opened for user 30 by (uid=0)   then removed session NN  new session 31  of user XX  pam_unix (sshd:session) session closed for user XX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got typo in the `sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem sftp intenal-sftp
```

should be

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it.  I had a dejavu moment. as I've seen same answer to different issue.  probably I copied the code from the same place. but didn't think I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

this should handle it for you

```
    Match Group somegroup,!admin
     PasswordAuthentication yes
     ChrootDirectory %h
     X11Forwarding no
     AllowTcpForwarding no
     ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Comment: but admin user is not part of somegroup already.   but not sure why using subsystem internal-sftp disables sftp access to admin

Comment: Match Group *, !admin